# Is it Possible to Add a Custom Acceptance Page to Logon with Amazon

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, google-oauth, login-with-amazon

I have a Google SmartHome app where Google requires a "special" acceptance/disclaimer page to the Google SmartHome device.  We are currently using a custom OAuth 2.0 server and have our own logon page.  The additional logon page is not an issue for the current setup.   This is similar to the standard Logon wth Amazon (LWA) page that asks if the user agrees to allow the app to access profile information.  Is it possible to customize that page or add an additional page to the process.  For an additional intervening page I was thinking something like:

- Use a URL to a non LWA site that presents a disclaimer web page
- Display our disclaimer
- redirect somehow back to LWA to finish the OAuth sequence

The below code block doesn't work of course.  It's meant to be more pseudocode. I somehow need to do a new GET with the OAuth parameters and then somehow "get out of the way"/redirect back to the initial SmartHome request.

```
[httpGet] 
public ActionResult Index(string client_id, string redirect_uri, string state, string scope, string response_type)
        {
            ViewBag.Client_id = client_id;
            ViewBag.Redirect_uri = redirect_uri;
            ViewBag.State = state;
            ViewBag.Scope = scope;
            ViewBag.Response_type = response_type;

            return View();
        }
[httpPost] 
public ActionResult Accept(string client_id, string redirect_uri, string state, string scope, string response_type)
        {
           //don't know how return the query string
           return RedirectPermanentPreserveMethod("https://www.amazon.com/ap/oa");
        }
...
```

Answer (score 0):

So not so hard if you just look at the documentation for the redirectPermenent

```
public ActionResult Index(string client_id, string redirect_uri, string state, string scope, string response_type)
        {
            ViewBag.Client_id = client_id;
            ViewBag.Redirect_uri = redirect_uri;
            ViewBag.State = state;
            ViewBag.Scope = scope;
            ViewBag.Response_type = response_type;

            return View();  //disclaimer 
        }
[httpPost] 
public ActionResult Accept(string client_id, string redirect_uri, string state, string scope, string response_type)
        {
          string uri = "https://www.amazon.com/ap/oa?" + "client_id=" + Client_id + "&redirect_uri=" + Redirect_uri + "&state=" + State + "&scope=" + Scope + "&response_type=" + Response_type;
           return RedirectPermanentPreserveMethod(uri);
        }
'''
```